# Combinations of continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis

Determine the points of continuity:
$g(x) := \sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}$, where $x\ge 0$.

I am having trouble even defining the composite functions to begin with... *Brain Freeze

Comment: On what domain is $f_1(x) = \sqrt{x}$ continuous; thus on what domain is $f_2(x) = x + \sqrt{x}$ continuous; and hence on what domain is $g(x)$ continuous?

Comment: Perfect! Would I need to prove the continuity of each individual function before I apply the composition of continuous functions theorems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sqrt x$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$. The sum of two continuous functions is continuous, so $x + \sqrt x$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$. Finally $\sqrt x$ is again continuous on $[0, \infty)$ which is the image of $[0, \infty)$ under $x + \sqrt x$ so the composition $g$ is continuous on $[0, \infty)$.